# What is the diminutive form of "Insula"?

Tags: diminutive

I recently had to look for various diminutives from latin words, however I got stuck when I had to find the diminutive for "*Insula*".
After many researches on the Internet I came across some ideas such as "*Insulitta*" (but I think the "-*ittus*, -*itta*" suffix is only used for proper nouns) or "*Insulla*/*Insella*". But I can't find any informations about the diminutive of insula, so I'm not sure it is the right way to write it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Cassell's Latin Dictionary* translates the English word "islet" to Latin as **parva insula**.

The *Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources* (DMLBS) contains the word **insuleta** / **insuletta**, defined as "islet, small island". ( https://logeion.uchicago.edu/insuleta ) But this is not attested until the 13th century (so the late medieval period).

As you mentioned, *-ula* is a diminutive suffix.  Lewis & Short's Latin Dictionary actually contains **insulula** but dismisses it as simply a "false reading for insula".

Comment: Thank you a lot! It solves my problem! :D

Answer (score 10):

Not all words have attested diminutive forms. And while there are patterns to forming diminutives, they are only simple for some types of words.

Many Latin nouns ending in *-ula* were diminutives themselves; but not all (it doesn't seem to be the case for *insula*). Words ending in *-ula* sometimes had diminutives where *-ula* is replaced with *-ella,* as in *[fistella](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfistella)* from *fistula* and *[sitella](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsitella)* from *situla.* There are also diminutives ending in *-illa,* such as *[papilla](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpapilla)* from *papula* and *[maxilla](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmaxilla)* from *mala.*

Diminutives did not commonly end in *-ulla.* (It looks like there might be a few possible examples.)

So in theory, either *insella* or *insilla* look like plausible or reasonable diminutives formed from *insula,* but I don't know of any evidence that they have ever been used (so I wouldn't recommend using them yourself).

I found a passage from 1843 that claims that "Insilla est diminutivum ab insula, et dicitur parva insula."

(page 153, [Fratris Felicis Fabri Evagatorum, in Terrae Sanctae, Arabiae et Egypti Peregrinationem; Edidit Cunradus Dietericus Hassler](https://books.google.com/books?id=OQ4mAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22insilla%22+%22insula%22&source=bl&ots=GBq198tFyJ&sig=ACfU3U1ZTCHC48tUVeWt4uKe9vtT8-fxLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiShe2J2q_rAhUyKX0KHVu0Bi8Q6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22insilla%22%20%22insula%22&f=false))